# XCTest Coverage after guard statement

Tags: code-coverage, xctest, xcode7

I've tried a new feature of XCode7 - Test Coverage.
Whenever I have a method with guard statement at the beginning report doesn't cover code after it even I hit it multiple times.
To prove it I made a breakpoint in "uncovered code". Then I run the test and made a screenshot. Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. I believe it's a bug. Care to file a radar? https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Xcode 7 Beta 4 (along with the nasty highlighting it used to do):

[image]